# Identity for Jacobian determinant

Tags: multivariable-calculus, jacobian

For an application in thermodynamics, I want to prove the identity
$$
\frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(x,y)} = \left[\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}\right]^{-1}\, \Leftrightarrow\, \frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(x,y)}\cdot \frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)} = 1,
$$
where $u = u(x,y)$ and $v = v(x,y)$ are functions of two variables. Thus, we can implicitly solve for $x = x(u,v)$ and $y = y(s,t)$, assuming that all partial derivatives exist and the assumptions of the implicit function theorem are satisfied. Moreover, I denote by
$$
\frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(x,y)} = \det 
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}|_{y} & \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}|_{x} \\
\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}|_{y} & \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}|_{x} \\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
I want to calculate this directly which gives
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(x,y)}\cdot \frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)} &= \det
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}|_{y} & \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}|_{x} \\
\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}|_{y} & \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}|_{x} \\
\end{pmatrix}\cdot\det
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}|_{v} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial v}|_{u} \\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}|_{v} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial v}|_{u} \\
\end{pmatrix} \\
&= \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}|_{y}\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}|_{x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}|_{v}\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}|_{u}-\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}|_{y}\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}|_{x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}|_{u}\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}|_{v}\\
& -\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}|_{x}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}|_{y}\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}|_{v}\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}|_{u}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}|_{x}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}|_{y}\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}|_{u}\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}|_{v},
\end{align}
but I cannot see why the last expression equals $1$.

Comment: Look at the product of the matrices....

Comment: You mean by making use of $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$?

Comment: That's the idea!